# Using Ctrl-F to Find on Page in AG Grid only Searches the Visible Field

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using AG Grid in React and when I try to find something in the table using 'CTRL-F', or 'find on page' within the browser, it only finds the text that is in the visible portion of the screen.

Here's an example:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/accessing-data/#example-using-for-each

Find the AG Grid example on the page Using. Press Ctrl-F and search for "Alain Bernard". It returns 0 results.

Now scroll all the way to the bottom of the AG Grid display. A search for "Alain Bernard" now shows 1 result.

My understanding was that the information loaded in AG Grid is rendered and represented on the webpage, just like any other text. Is there a setting that I am not enabling here? I couldn't find documentation about it on their website, however I may not be using the right terminology.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried using AG Grid's (quick filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-quick/)? Maybe this could help.

Comment: Also AG-grid only renders a subset of complete data on a given time and re-renders as user scrolls up or down. it is not possible to find all the occurances using ctrl+F. if all the rows are rendered at once it will defeat the purpose of using AG-grid isnt it?

Comment: @sandeepjoshi, this is a pretty ridiculous reply. It does not have anything to do with my question. Is it possible to just render all occurrences at once? I am using paging on the results so it will inherently not be storing the entirety of the results on the page. But either way, my question is whether it is at all possible to use Ctrl-F on the entire page of results.

Comment: @ViqMontana this looks like a good fix for this.